# Having an interactive menu when running a shell command

Tags: tmux, fish

I have this line in my `.tmux.conf` file.

`bind-key q run "fish --interactive -c q"`

The code for function `q` is written in fish. This is the code.

```
function q 
    set session (t ls | fzf)
    set chosen (string split ":" $session)

    t switch -t $chosen[1]
end
```

What `q` does is simple. Pipe the output from the output for `t ls`, which is `tmux ls`, into fzf. Then split the string by `:` and then switch tmux sessions.

When I run `q` normally as a command in fish, it works fine. The fzf ui shows up and I can switch sessions.

But when I use the keybinding I set. It lets me change sessions but an interactive window does not appear. It just switches sessions without letting me choose.

What I want is to be able to have an interactive menu when I use `prefix-q`. So that I can choose which session I want to switch to.

Answer (score 1):

When tmux invokes your `bind-key` shell command, it does so without any tmux pane active. That is, it runs the shell detached from any tty, because a tmux command might switch panes, or create a new pane, or destroy one; so it runs in a void.

The right idea is use tmux bindings to control tmux, and shell bindings to run commands in the current shell instance, which may in turn talk to tmux. Try this (as a shell command, not in tmux.conf):

```
bind \cTb q
```

This is a shell binding. Now 'control-T' followed by 'b' will run the menu in whatever pane is active.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should create a new tmux pane and run `q` in that new pane. And have the output in that pane go back into the pane where I ran the command?

Comment: My assumption was that you had some pane active, and wanted to bring up a menu in that pane, in which case the shell binding is the right approach. If you want to create a new pane, I think you will have to create the pane and then use `tmux send-keys` to direct keypresses at that pane.

Comment: No. I want the command to run in the same pane where I used to keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the command capture alters the stdin/stdout/stderr file descriptors that `fzf` is handed. Try forcing it to interact with the tty:

```
set session (t ls | fzf 2>/dev/tty)
```